# Interacting with a Windows Executable in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible for an ASP.net website to launch and interact with a windows executable application written in .NET?  For example, is there a type of plugin that can load and integrate a windows application into an ASP.NET website?

Is this something that Silverlight can be used for?

Comment: Remember that an ASP.NET application is basically a piece of HTML and JavaScript that runs in a browser. No, a browser cannot launch an .EXE on the client.

Comment: Can you use silverlight to utilize the Windows APIS and to emulate a WinForm via a browser?

Comment: It's still running in a browser, so no, you can't do it.

Comment: The closest you can get is rebuilding the entire .Net exe as a Silverlight plug-in, and even this may not be possible if you need parts of the framework that aren't available to Silverlight.

Comment: Do you want this executable to run on the client or on the server?

Comment: It can run on the client.  The program I am creating is complex, it involves MIDI and graphical music input.  I am using a DLL that is written in C, but using P/Invoke to call the unmanaged APIS so that I can use the DLL in .NET.  I have no idea if I can write a program like this in Silverlight as a plugin so that it can be used via the internet.

Comment: You can't P/Invoke from Silverlight.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn You can in silverlight 5 with elevated trust: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2011/09/27/pinvoke-in-silverlight5-and-net-framework.aspx

Comment: @iamkrillin, thank you.  You've helped me verify that my project can most likely be completed with Silverlight 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Process is not available for silverlight applications. For what you can use [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You *might* be able to do something with reflection and file system access if you are running with elevated trust.  This is a big might.  Also the steps required to configure this are not exacetly straight forward, and for good reason.

so far as running applications from the browser with straight HTML and js.  Nope.  Not going to happen.

What I have done in the past is write a java applet sign it and deploy it in such a way that will allow it to completley escape the security sandbox.  Note:  there are several steps required to do this which I will not go into here.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is No.  Don't waste your time on this.

Short Answer Alternative 1:  Recreate the Windows App as an ASP.NET Web Application

Short Answer Alternative 2:  Look for a website online that offers the same functionality as your Windows App and then reference and embed it in your Asp.Net Website using an IFrame.  (This can get complicated depending on if data is stored rather then displayed but its do-able)

Answer (score 0):

In trusted mode (ask your hosting provider), you can manipulate with this executable by loading it's code via `[Assembly.LoadFrom][1]` find type and invoke a method.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Sample.Assembly.dll");
Type t = assembly.GetType("MyAssembly.MyClass");
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t, new object[2]{1234, 5678});
var result = methodInfo.Invoke(o, new object[2]{"param1","param2"});
```

You can use AJAX to interact with a user.